# Freewall gutter spacing

Tags: javascript, grid

I am working with freewall. http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/

Trying to get 0 margin or 0 "gutter" in freewall terms. Here's my html

```
<div class="free_wall">  
    <div class="brick"></div>  
    <div class="brick"></div>  
    <div class="brick"></div>  
    <div class="brick"></div>  
    <div class="brick"></div>  
    <div class="brick"></div>
    <div class="brick"></div>  
    <div class="brick"></div> 
</div>
```

Here's my css:

```
.free_wall {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    .brick {
       background: rgb(135, 199, 135);
       width: 320px;
       height: 320px;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }
```

Heres my code:

```
$(function() {
    var wall = new freewall(".free_wall");
    wall.fitZone();
    //wall.refresh();
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
        gutterY: 0,
        gutterX: 0,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Please call reset method (for setting freewall) before call fitZone

```
$(function() {
    var wall = new freewall(".free_wall");


    wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
        gutterY: 0,
        gutterX: 0
    });

    wall.fitZone();

});
```

Best